# Hide vtkOutlineGlowPass behind other objects

Tags: python, rendering, vtk

I am looking for a method to show the outline of a polydata object. I found an example using vtkOutlineGlowPass that almost do the job: https://examples.vtk.org/site/Python/Rendering/OutlineGlowPass/.

It nicely illustrate the outline for a single polydata object. However, the outline glows through other polydata objects that are overlaid with the outline-polydata object ([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYcDg.png)).
What I'm aiming for is that the outline is hidden behind other objects ([Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI1i0.png)).

I'm using python (3.10) and vtk (9.2.2).